# Strange enough! http://laravel6.com is pointing to local host 127.0.0.1 - Every system in my office

Tags: localhost

[image: laravel6.com pointing to local host]

Nothing related to this found anywhere on web.

[image: No results about this on google]

This is the only place I found something about this.

https://www.robtex.com/dns-lookup/laravel6.com

Is it something to worry about?

Comment: I am curious, how did you find this?! It resolves to 127.0.0.0 on my box too - there record is setup that way I think

Comment: You are correct @urban but that's not the point. Point is why would someone do this? and back in 2014?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Offcource no need to worrry!
we can change apache default IP address http://127.0.0.1/ to any example.com like this

this domain definately not working globally on internet